# Why is the max function applied on a dictionary not giving the maximum value but retuning the key with maximum value?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why the following code is returning the output as 'c' instead of 7 even though we are checking the dictionary values in the lambda function?

```
>>> a={'a': 1, 'c': 7, 'b': 5, 'd': 5}
>>> max(a, key=lambda x:a[x])
'c'
>>>
```

Comment: Because when you iterate over a `dict` you iterate over the keys.  To get the maximum value, try `max(a.values())`

Comment: Pass the key back to the `dict`:  `a.get(max(a, key=a.get))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iteration over a dictionary happens over the keys by default. Another way to see what's going on in your case is to call `list`, which also iterates over the keys by default:

```
>>> list(a)
['a', 'c', 'b', 'd']
```

You explicitly specify iteration over the values, using `.values`.

```
>>> max(a.values())
7
```

If you want both key as well as value, you can call `max` over `.items`:

```
>>> max(a.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
('c', 7)
```

`.items` returns a tuple in python2.x, you can have `max` iterate over it and pick the tuple corresponding to the `max` value in the 2nd position of each tuple.

Comment: Thank you, Yes it is correct but confusing logic, suddenly not able to get the idea :) counterintuitive